# Show list from last file to first save

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to reverse the result displayed in a Combobox.
The last saved file would appear first, currently it is the opposite. it appears with this code:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test\",*.TXT");

foreach (string file in files)
{
  comboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
}
```

According to my research, the solution would be:

```
.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
```

added somewhere. But I don't know. Every attempt I've made has been unsuccessful.

Currently:

```
101-00.06.52.TXT
101-00.06.54.TXT
101-00.06.56.TXT
```

Desired outcome:

```
101-00.06.56.TXT
101-00.06.54.TXT
101-00.06.52.TXT
```

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of static method [`Directory.GetFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-6.0#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_) method, use [`GetFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-6.0#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_GetFiles_System_String_) method from `DirectoryInfo` class. Apply `OrderByDescending()` on it.

---

[**Directory.GetFiles():**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-6.0)

> Returns the **names of files** that meet specified
> criteria

Vs

[**DirectoryInfo.GetFiles():**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-6.0#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_GetFiles_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)

> Returns a **file list** from the current directory.

---

Like,

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Test\"); //Get the Directory information

var allTxtFiles = di.GetFiles("*.txt") //Get all files based on search pattern
     .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationTime)  //Sort by CreationTime
     .Select(x => x.Name);  //Select only name from FileInfo object

foreach (string file in allTxtFiles)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
}
```

Comment: Oh yes is the good solution thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason why you problem. But if you want to receive correct result is simple. First try this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test\",*.TXT");
comboBox1.ItemsSource = files;
```

if the result is not correct. Use this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test\",*.TXT");
files = files.Reverse();
comboBox1.ItemsSource = files;
```